# How can I create a report that returns a 2 separate values each time an instance of a third value is found in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Spreadsheet with about 50 tabs, each tab represents a homeroom for a different group of students at my school. I want to create a new sheet that lists all instances of a particular request by a given "requesting teacher" and returns the name of each student that was requested and which homeroom (tab) the student is in.

Here's a link to my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X0YElQCm_felOoGdNoxt5jfIAO7SSWrEjvEuQvHvYyU/edit#gid=677216877

I have tried using the =FILTER function but it doesn't do what I want.

Here's an image of what I'd like to do, only programmatically instead of manually

[image]

So I want a function that will search all tabs and every time "Barker" appears, return the name of the student requested by "Barker" along with the name of the homeroom that student is in. The homeroom would be the tab name where the instance was found.

Comment: (Your google spreadsheet isn't shared)

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: I've made the sheet viewable now.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I'd recommend against using tabs aka sheets for scaling things that may not be bounded. Is it possible to put all students in one sheet, and add a column for their homeroom teacher? (Or do other data/features prevent easily doing that?)

Anyway, if you don't change your setup, I think the way I'd do it is create 50 columns, and have a cell at the top with each sheet's name. Then below that cell, use the `indirect` formula to programmatically create the sheet reference, then filter for students who have the preferred name.

[image: screenshot of example spreadsheet]

```
=filter(indirect(D1&"!A1:A"),indirect(D1&"!B1:B")="Kate")
```

Does that get you what you want?

And good luck pairing up the students with their preferred teacher, thank you for taking their preference into account!

Comment: I don't think this will do what I want. Sorry.

Comment: Well, can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the indirect function but from what I can tell, I would have to create a version of the function for every student in the school, which would be unfeasible.

Comment: No, just for each teacher.